# Split or trim string into one line

Tags: c++, string, std

I have a String which looks like this :

> string str = "1. Hallo \n2.Hello\n3.Bonjour\n4.Merhaba\n";

in the end I want to have sth like that:

> string str_line_3 = "3.Bonjour\n";

Im searching here for easy methods. 
To find the '\n' in a loop is to ugly imo !

Ideas ?

edit: I want to find it through a parameter which wants a Line Number f.ex Line 3

Comment: looking for \n might be ugly in your opinion,  but it's actually a really easy method. If you want to do something else, you might want to change the way you store this string first.

Comment: There have to be a easy function right ?

Comment: `To find the '\n' in a loop is to ugly imo !` Then how do you suppose to find newlines without actually finding newlines. And ugly compared to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

```
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main()
{
  std::string input = "1. Hallo \n2.Hello\n3.Bonjour\n4.Merhaba\n";
  std::string line;
  std::istringstream sline(input);
  while(std::getline(sline,line))
  {
    std::cout << line << '\n';
  }
}
```